# What can cause the failure of an SSRS Report on the Reportserver on Rendering?

Tags: sql-server, debugging, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Details are as follows:

Environment:

SSRS 2008 Server, SQL Server 2008 for database, Report Developed in SQL Server Business Intelligence Devlopment Studio - Reporting Project

Error Messages:

"An error occurred during client rendering."
"An error has occurred during report processing."
"Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSource1'."
"For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors "

I have done that (navigation & all that) and the result was that a parameter of a scalar variable needs to be declared. The funny thing is that those variables are properly declared in the datasource and in  the report sources everywhere. Also this report/datasource worked no problem on SSRS 2005. In the Development Environment the report runs perfectly. On the server the report only fails when executing and after the parameters have been accepted. We use no stored procedures.

Any help / ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced problems in SSRS 2005 where deploying changes to a report didn't properly update changes to parameters, in particular newly added parameters.  The fix was to delete the existing report using Report Manager and then upload the modified version.

Hope this helps,

Bill

Answer (score 1):

When you run in the Dev environment, you're using your windows credentials.  Do you also use your windows credentials when you run through SSRS? or are you using different credentials?

Comment: I am using different credentials, although all our other reports are similar and we have no problems. The report is quite happy with using the datasource until it attempts to render the result.

Comment: Are you using any Synonyms?  Could it be a security problem tied to the credentials used by SRS?